# How to modify widget config programmatically?

Tags: arcgis-web-appbuilder

I have created custom widget in WAB developer edition V2.9.

I want to change value programmatically in widget config. On run time I am able to set value using below code but does not update in config file.

```
this.config.tempProperty = "Test" ;
```

If I refresh application then tempProperty still showing old value.

Is there any way to update widget config programatically?

Regards,

Prashant